# Returning specific values at any given index in the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, fibonacci

I am trying to output the value at any given indices in the Fibonacci sequence using recursion for my coding assignment. Can anyone explain why my function `fibonacci` is not returning the correct values that it should? I can seem to find the bug that causing an error message to pop up saying "invalid pointer."

any help is appreciated.

```
fibonacciType1 fibonacci(int index, int counter, BigNumber FibVal, vector<BigNumber>FibList) {

   if ((index == counter)) { // base cases
      return FibList[index];
   }
   else { // recursion step
      if (counter == 0){
         return FibList[0];
      }
      else{
          FibVal += FibList[index - 1];
          FibList.push_back(FibVal);
          ++index;
          fibonacci(index, counter, FibVal, FibList);
      }
   }
}

int main() {

   cout << "Do not change this line.  Enter a sequence of increasing Fibonacci indicies and -1 to stop input." << endl;

   // Section 1
   // *** insert here a loop to input Fibonacci indexes and calculate Fibonacci numbers, or input -1 to stop input ***

   int counter{0};

   while (
         cin >> counter,
         -1 != counter) {

      int index{1};
      BigNumber FibVal{1};
      vector<BigNumber> FibList{0,1};

      cout << counter << endl;
      cout << fibonacci(index, counter, FibVal, FibList) << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Passing `FibList` by value would be my immediate guess at the cause, without even reading the rest of your program. This is the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger. It will be quite liberating when you discover that you can pause your program after every line of code and examine the values of your variables.

Comment: Turn on warnings (or increase level). Your function doesn't return in the recursive case.